# Django: reconstruct structured parameters sent via $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I'm sending an Ajax request (with jQuery) with structured post data:

```
$.post(
    myUrl,
    {
         items: [{code: 'a', description: 'aaa'},
                {code: 'b', description: 'bbb'}]
    })
```

what I see in `request.POST` is:

```
<QueryDict: {u'items[0][code]': [u'a'],
             u'items[0][description]': [u'aaa'],
             u'items[1][description]': [u'bbb'],
             u'items[1][code]': [u'b']}>
```

How can I process the request to obtain the original `items`?

(Note that `request.POST.get('items')` doesn't work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made special library for Django/Python to handle structured data sent through requests. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser).

Comment: Good! That's exactly what I needed. Now, I've adopted another solution, but I'll use yours in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you post your object as JSON. In Django, you then can recreate the structure by parsing the JSON into python objects.

Post JSON with jQuery

```
$.post(
    myUrl,
    JSON.stringify({
         items: [{code: 'a', description: 'aaa'},
                {code: 'b', description: 'bbb'}]
    })
)
```

Parsing JSON in Django view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
        # json_data contains your objects
        print json_data['items']

    return HttpResponse("Got data")
```

Comment: Thanks. I adopted a slight different solution: send `items : JSON.slugify(...)` and decode with `simplejson.loads(request.POST['items'])`

Comment: Yeah, +1, although I tend to prefer @Don's version (fits with HTTP's key/value format a bit better), but the idea is the same.

Comment: From Django 1.6 use request.body instead of request.raw_post_data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
request.POST.getlist('items')
```