# Reading multidimensional arrays from a POST request in Django

Tags: jquery, django, post

I have a jquery client that is sending a POST request with a multidimensional array, something like this:

> ```
> friends[0][id]    12345678 
> friends[0][name]  Mr A
> friends[1][id]    78901234
> friends[1][name]  Mr B
> ```

That is, an array of two items, name and id.

Is there an automatic way to receive this input as list or a dictionary? I can't seem to be able to make .getlist work

Comment: Show us the jQuery code. That's not the normal format for multi-valued elements in HTTP POSTs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - see DrMeers' answer bellow, it shows the issue I'm running into but I was looking for a better solution..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related with [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899143/django-reconstruct-structured-parameters-sent-via-post). As stated there, I made special library for Django/Python to handle multidimensional arrays sent through requests. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser).

Comment: Thanks Berni. I ended up doing what Herman suggested but I think this solution is cleaner..

Answer (score 7):

DrMeers' link is no longer valid, so I'll post another method of achieving the same thing. It's also not perfect, and it would be much better if Django had such a function built-in. But, since it doesn't:

[Converting Multi-dimensional Form Arrays in Django](http://www.ironzebra.com/news/23/converting-multi-dimensional-form-arrays-in-django)

Disclaimer: I wrote that post. The essence of it is in this function, which could be more robust, but it works for arrays of one-level objects:

```py
    def getDictArray(post, name):
        dic = {}
        for k in post.keys():
            if k.startswith(name):
                rest = k[len(name):]
                
                # split the string into different components
                parts = [p[:-1] for p in rest.split('[')][1:]
                print parts
                id = int(parts[0])
                
                # add a new dictionary if it doesn't exist yet
                if id not in dic:
                    dic[id] = {}
                    
                # add the information to the dictionary
                dic[id][parts[1]] = post.get(k)
        return dic
```

Comment: Thanks Herman.. not *exactly* what I needed but close enough. I think a more accurate result would return a list of dictionaries and not a dictionary of dictionary, but it's more or less the same. Again, thank you!

Comment: @Liorsion: by replacing the last line with "return [item for key, item in sorted(dic.items())]" you'll have the corresponding list as return object.

Answer (score 4):

Does this help? http://dfcode.com/blog/2011/1/multi-dimensional-form-arrays-and-django/

> If you want POST data, the only way to get it is to specify the exact ‘name’ you are looking for:
>
> ```
>     person[1].name = request.POST['person[1][name]']
>     person[1].age = request.POST['person[1][age]']
>     person[2].name = request.POST['person[2][name]']
>     person[2].age = request.POST['person[2][age]']
> ```
>
> Here is a quick on-the-fly workaround in Python when you have the need to extract form values without explicitly typing the full name as a string:
>
> ```
>     person_get = lambda *keys: request.POST[
>         'person' + ''.join(['[%s]' % key for key in keys])]
> ```
>
> Now when you need information, throw one of these suckers in and you’ll have much wider flexibility. Quick example:
>
> ```
>     person[1].name = person_get('1', 'name')
>     person[1].age = person_get('1', 'age')
>     person[2].name = person_get('2', 'name')
>     person[2].age = person_get('2', 'age')
> ```

Comment: The link is broken. Please summarize the information in this answer, or it needs to be deleted due to lacking any context. That's why answering with just a link is a bad idea, they tend to break from time to time.

Comment: @DrMeers How do i know how many person objects there? Ex. one submits upto person[2] and another submission includes upto person [11]